# Listen for events from dynamically created components

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a C# MVC 5 application. One page in particular has a bootstrap accordion style list of categories, each of which has a hidden list of items that are shown when the category is clicked (expanded). These components (the categories and items) each have a checkbox next to them. I've implemented some server-side mumbo-jumbo that when all items under a category are checked, the category itself is checked too. Sort of a "check all items in this category" functionality. I'm trying to do this client side now; the user checks the category and automatically all items under it are checked too. The hard part is that these categories and their associated items are rendered dynamically depending on what the application finds in our database.

E.g. (this is just a sample slice to illustrate my problem)

```
@*some div stuff*@
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
  @*here I have a way to get a unique id for this category*@
  @*some divs and headers go here*@
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => category.IsChecked)
  @*some other headers like name, description, etc*@
  @*also code to handle the accordion-style collapsing/expanding*@

  @if (category.Items.Any())
  {
    @*some div stuff here*@
    @foreach (var item in category.Items)
    {
      @*some div and header stuff here*@
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => item.IsChecked)
      @*some other headers like name, description, etc*@
    }
  }
}
```

That's it in a nutshell. I know I could add ids to the above checkboxes like:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(d => category.IsChecked, new {id = @categoryId})
```

Where categoryId is a unique identifier for that category, but as each identifier is different, I can't figure out how to listen for its events.

I need some sort of jQuery magic, a hope and a prayer here!

I'm aware of listening for checkbox changes using:

```
$(document).on('change', '#someId', function(s, e) {
      alert('alert!');
    });
```

But the above situation is hurting my brain as I won't know what id to supply this event listener or kinds like it...

I'm sure something like this has been encountered by someone out there. I'm rather inexperienced and have reached the edge of my understanding unfortunately.

Kindest regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically added components, if you need to handle the events then it needs to be handled differently,by attaching the events to one the static component on your page under which your new components are being added.

this type of events is called delegated events.

`$(document).on('change', '<selector>', function(event) {
      //process the event
 });`

The `<selector>` here should be the selector of the element which will be the parent tag for the new elements.

More information can be found at `jquery` forum

**Reference:http://api.jquery.com/on/**

Answer (score 0):

`.on` is only for exist item now.

If you want to bind event to all new created item, you need to use `.delegate()`